# Can't boot Ubuntu Live on Windows 10

Tags: usb, windows-10

So, I've heard gleaming things about Linux, so I decided to get an Ubuntu Live USB to try it out. I set it up with the instructions from the official Ubuntu website, yet When I go to Windows BIOS settings and select boot from USB, I can't find my USB on there. Can someone help?

Comment: Windows 10 doesn't shutdown fully when you select "Shutdown" from the Power menu. Choose restart instead and then enter BIOS settings when it reboots.

Answer (score 0):

**Ensure your computer is running the latest BIOS available. This is important because an out-of-date BIOS can have bugs, and those bugs sometimes affect things like UEFI, non-Windows operating systems, or other components.**

★ **Make sure your USB is bootable.** [Make a Pendrive Bootable](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#4-boot-selection-and-partition-scheme)

> **Condition 1:**

- If You selected Target System **BIOS (or UEFI-CSM)**. (When Making USB Bootable.)

  - Change Your PC BIOS boot mode to **UEFI**.   [Change Pc BIOS Boot Mode](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23161_01/html/E37044/glsem.html)
  - Now, Retry to boot with USB.

> **Condition 2:**

- If You selected Target System **MBR**. (When Making USB Bootable.)

  - Change Your PC BIOS boot mode to **Legacy**.   [Change Pc BIOS Boot Mode](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23161_01/html/E37044/glsem.html)
  - Now, Retry to boot with USB.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the bootable USB again. Use Universal USB installer or Rufus (for UEFI).